# Backpropagation and batch training

Tags: batch-file, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

Backpropagation calculates `dW` (weight delta) per weight per pattern, so it's straightforward how to modify weights when doing stochastic training. How do I use it for batch training, though? Simply accumluate `dW` over the entire training set and then apply the modfication, or is there more to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just accumluate dW over the entire training set.  At least that is how I coded it back in grad school...

Comment: But when you recalculate the input weights, you are supposed to use (an?) input vector. So, say I accumulate the errors for 2 vectors, then I start doing backprop - which vector do I choose? Do I run backprop with one vector, updating all the weights, then run backprop with the other vector, re-updating all the weights?

Comment: @dwanderson Did you determine how to do this? I'm stuck in the same spot you are, I have accumulated all of the deltas over the entire batch, but not sure how to proceed from here. My assumption as of now is to set the deltas to the average delta, then update the weights for each vector in my dataset.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a lot with the different gradients from the different samples. That includes higher order information (approximate 2nd derivative) or conjugate gradient or natural gradient or ... :)